# pulsating text doesn't works

Tags: html, css

I have created a pulsating text with HTML and CSS to be displayed by rotating the smartphone screen horizontally. The text, composed of small circles and implemented with div elements with a radius, should pulse at 21 hertz.
The CSS code for the circle class is:

```
.circle {
            width: 3vw;
            height: 3vw;
            background-color: transparent;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); /* Aggiungi un'ombra per sfumare i contorni */
            animation: pulsate 0.0476s linear infinite; /* 47.6 milliseconds per cycle (21Hz) */
            
        }
@keyframes pulsate {
            0% {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); /* Luce bianca */
            }
            50% {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* Luce bianca più intensa */
            }
            100% {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); /* Torna alla luce bianca originale */
            }
        }
```

On the desktop, it pulsates regularly, but on smartphones, the pulsation is irregular. It doesn't happen on all smartphones. On some, it pulsates regularly, while on others, it seems to stutter. Can someone provide an explanation and a solution?

I tried to use JavaScript but it works worse.
I can't reduce the frequency because I need just 21hz.

Comment: Which smartphones are giving a problem.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this problem is by leaving the "pulsation" all alone. Nowadays, everything is blinking and pulsating... give your eyes a little rest. A simple and clean website will increase the peace of the world in any case.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but the pulsating is the pourpose. It derives from a special study that this particular write at a certain frequency brings benefit to the brain

Comment: By the way, I solved the problem deleting all the css instructions to build the write and simply placed an image. Because of the lightness of the code it pulsate without interruptions.